# Can I store an array of objects in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, nosql

Does CouchDB support array type? Can I store an array of objects in CouchDB for one of the fields in one of my documents?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Thanks, what other types are supported in couchDB? Object, Array, String, Boolean, Integer; that's all right?

Comment: Whatever types the documentation says.

Comment: All the types that you mentioned! user3421904

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this example?

```
//Create some users
var user1 = {name: 'modulus admin', age: 42, roles: ['admin', 'moderator', 'user']};
var user2 = {name: 'modulus user', age: 22, roles: ['user']};
var user3 = {name: 'modulus super admin', age: 92, roles: ['super-admin', 'admin', 'moderator', 'user']};

// Insert some users
collection.insert([user1, user2, user3], function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Inserted %d documents into the "users" collection. The documents inserted with "_id" are:', result.length, result);
  }
  //Close connection
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: Something similar; I'm using nano instead. so here you are adding user1, user2 and user 3 as an array of objects for one row or it will be three rows? I guess what I'm looking for is : var user1 = {name: 'modulus admin', age: 42, roles: [{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]};

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB can store any kind of JSON data in a single document, which of course includes arrays of objects.